# What happened on May 17 2:56?

Tags: support

Apparently 32 people got the [generalist badge](https://travel.stackexchange.com/help/badges/15/generalist) at the very same minute. What triggered this avalanche?

Comment: The top tags perhaps changed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> there must be at least 200 questions in all 40 of the top tags before this badge is awarded to anyone -- [announcement of the badge](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/05/generalist-badge-implemented/)

On May 17, 2015, this site fulfilled  the above criterion, unlocking the badge: consequently, a badge-issuing script (which runs at some intervals) showered it on users.

It's hard to say precisely what question in what tag was the last one the site needed, since old questions get deleted for various reason. It *might* have been [Do you physically need a license to drive in the US?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/47721) which is tagged [us-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/us-citizens), this tag currently being tied for 40th on the site. But this guess is more likely to be wrong than right.